# Get nested button id in header

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to reference my button (which is nested inside my header/nav), to make an event `onclick`, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Tried nesting `getElementByName` with `getElementById` tried some `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`

Tried:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('hdr');
var y= x.querySelector('hdrBtns');
z = y.getElementById('singUp');
```

Tried:

```
const brt = document.querySelectorAll('.hdr .hdrBtns');
const dac = brt.getElementById('signUp');
```

Code Underneath:

```
 <body>
        <header class="hdr">
            <div class="hLogo">
                <h1>
                    Test
                </h1>               
            </div>

            <nav class="hdrBtns">
                <button id="singUp">Sign Up</button>
                <button id="singIN">Sign In</button> 
                
            </nav>
        </header>
     <script src="./script.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Why not directly use the id to access the buttons?

Comment: try only const button = document.getElementById('signUp')

Comment: You could Accept an answer that help you the most

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) returned by `Element#querySelectorAll()` or `getElementsByClassName()` does not have Methods other Elements have, like `getElementById()` or `querySelector()`.

Assuming you only have one Element with your particular ID, like you should have, just selecting the element by this will work:

```js
let btn = document.querySelector("#singUp")

btn.addEventListener("click", () => alert("test"))
```

```html
<header class="hdr">
  <div class="hLogo">
    <h1>
      Test
    </h1>
  </div>

  <nav class="hdrBtns">
    <button id="singUp">Sign Up</button>
    <button id="singIN">Sign In</button>

  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: You know what's weird if I write this code myself it doesn't work but when I copy pasted it from what you wrote it worked... I may have been banging my head against the wall for no reason...

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to use this code:

```js
var signUp = document.getElementById('signUp');

signUp.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Do something...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the element is unique in your code, you could just `document.getElementById` as other people stated in their answers.

But if the id is not unique and you only want to get the element in the specific class. Try:

```js
let dac = document.querySelector('.hdr .hdrBtns #singUp')
console.log(dac)
```

```html
<header class="hdr">
            <div class="hLogo">
                <h1>
                    Test
                </h1>               
            </div>

            <nav class="hdrBtns">
                <button id="singUp">Sign Up</button>
                <button id="singIN">Sign In</button> 
                
            </nav>
        </header>
```

Comment: So I tried this and it gives me "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')" tried doing a window.onload and puting my script at the bottom of the body

Comment: @Really? You could click the run code snippet and you see it correctly output the  `<button id="singUp">Sign Up</button>`. The error is `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')` which means JavaScript is not able to add an event listener to an element for performing a function. if you want you could put `addEventlistener` code to you question since I doesn't see you have `eventListener` in your code

Comment: You know what's weird if I write this code myself it doesn't work but when I copy pasted it from what you wrote it worked... I may have been banging my head against the wall for no reason...

Comment: @Hope, please accept my answer if it help you:)

Answer (score 0):

A lot ways to do that. But If you looking for a element which already has an `id` then would be the best to use `getElementByID()` function. Otherwise you can use `querySelector` in many different ways.

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.hdr nav button');
let id1 = btns[0].getAttribute('id');
let id2 = btns[1].getAttribute('id');

console.log('v1',id1, id2)

const b1 = document.querySelector('.hdr nav button:first-child');
const b2 = document.querySelector('.hdr nav button:last-child');
console.log('v2', b1.getAttribute('id'), b2.getAttribute('id'));


const b3 = document.getElementById('singUp');
const b4 = document.querySelector('#singIN'); 
console.log('v3', b3.getAttribute('id'), b4.getAttribute('id'));
```

```html
<body>
        <header class="hdr">
            <div class="hLogo">
                <h1>
                    Test
                </h1>               
            </div>

            <nav class="hdrBtns">
                <button id="singUp">Sign Up</button>
                <button id="singIN">Sign In</button> 
                
            </nav>
        </header>
     <script src="./script.js"></script>
    </body>
```